# How to measure propulsive efficiency of a human powered boat?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, drag, inertia, propulsion

I am asking for help to measure the effective propulsive force and its effect on boat glide on a human powered vessel using a paddle.

Senario

A person using a paddle to propel a boat or canoe. Setting aside the weight of the vessel and body weight of the person as being constant. Provided the water is flat, undisturbed.

Question

How can I effectively measure the propulsive power of the strokes in relation to how they help move the boat. How can I assess the propulsive power in relation to the momentum and drag once the vessel is in motion (to figure what number of strokes become optimal in gliding the boat). The goal is to measure how effective the strokes are, not necessarily how fast from a to b, which can be timed. The lessons from the study would help the adoption or modification of more effective techniques.

Is there a simple device I can make with your creative help to get this relatively objective measure?

As a thought, I am imagining an hourglass set sideways. This is theoretical to help with ideas as I know it won't work realistically. Suppose as the boat moves forward, the forward thrust is going to displace sand inside to move back to the rear part of the hourglass. The amount of sand per number of strokes will help with measure. This is theoretical but I am looking for something realistic that can be used. Maybe a drag scale, a spring loaded drag box with a dial?

I would also like to understand the physics involved in more lay terms, please. Thank you!

Comment: This  to me is bordering on engineering as regards the measurements  you want to make, using say a controlled environment such as a swimming pool. No offence, but you have a lot of questions in your post, and the physics of paddling, drag etc are widely available on the Internet.  The policy here is to answer 1 or 2 related **physics** concept based questions. There are over 160 sites on SE , in particular engineering,  aquatic activities and biology based sites (as regards the human element)  might be more beneficial to you.

Comment: -1. What research have you done to find out methods already in use for this kind of measurement? eg googling "measure power of paddle stroke" returns Kayak Power Meter, among other relevant results.

Comment: The power meter is known for a while now, along with other paddle attached meters from Merlin. They don't really show what I'm asking. Maybe I should rewrite a bit more. It's the whole resulting effect, not the power output of the strokes. They are very erroneous. Any strong person can have strong output, but the output do not correspond to increased boat speed doe to many factors, most common is correct stroke mechanics. I would like to focus beyond the output. This is why I need help on the physics side to form the correct basis for the actual approach to measure.

Comment: Two people seems to express displeasure on the question and one offered helpful answer. Should I withdraw it or continue to clarify? I do sincerely need help from both forming the correct basis on the physics side to then approach the right tool to measure. So, yes, it would cross from physics to mechanics. I'm trying to help my athletes get more objective measures and ways to assess, and yes, I do know about other already existing devices. They haven't yet addressed this need sufficiently.

Comment: Your question is too broad in its present form, but there is nothing to stop you splitting it up  and focusing on the physics aspect of each of your separate queries. The trouble is, as you know,  that  your questions involve several different disciplines. For example your third and second last paragraphs are pure engineering, i.e. applied physical concepts. Your last line might be misunderstood here, you may have intended it as a summing up, we see it as "teach me physics" ;). Look at the **form and style** of the questions that get well received here and mimic those. Best of luck with v2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about the **propulsive efficiency** of the stroke. ie How much of the energy expended by the rower (input) results in useful work (output). The power meter seems to measure the input. The difficulty here seems to be **how to define useful work**.

Several articles available on the internet discuss how to measure rowing efficiency. For example, [Propulsive Efficiency of Oars](http://ruina.tam.cornell.edu/research/topics/locomotion_and_robotics/oar_efficiency.pdf) identifies the useful output as **overcoming boat drag**. It says that the maximum efficiency you can expect is about 80%.

To measure efficiency, you first need to calibrate the boat.

The power dissipated by boat drag is $P=Fv$ where $F$ is the force required to pull the boat along at speed $v$, the force being applied in the same direction as $v$. Experimentally you would need to tow the boat (laden with passive rower/s and oars - or the equivalent weight) with a constant force and measure the average speed through the water. Alternatively tow at constant speed relative to the water and note the average force.

You will need some kind of force meter. If towing from the water you can pull in the direction the boat moves, but you will need to avoid disrupting flow past the boat. If towing from land (eg on a canal towpath) you avoid disrupting the water ahead of the boat but the applied force is no longer in the direction the boat is moving, so you need to measure angles between the towlines and the direction of the boat, and apply geometry to calculate the applied force in the direction of motion. Ideally you would do the calibration in a water tunnel, varying water flow speed and measuring constant force in the direction of motion.

A graph of $P=Fv$ against $v$ gives you the calibration of boat dissipation power at various speeds.

You then measure the power exerted by the rower/s - eg using the power meter - and the speed achieved. The boat dissipation power (at the rowing speed) as a % of rowing power gives you the propulsive efficiency of the rower/s.

Answer (score 1):

The hard part here is the work measurement; the rest is a matter of of some kind of motion capture.

I suggest two possible schemes for doing the work measurement.

1. Instrument the boat for horizontal propulsive force and combine time series data with motion capture for distance. In the case of a row boat the easiest place to instrument the might be the oarlocks. In the cases of a paddled vehicle like a canoe, you might instrument the connection between the paddler's seat and the rest of the boat. In both cases you are interested in horizontal forces only because those are the ones that cause progress.
2. However, getting just the effective horizontal work doesn't actually capture the effort the human is putting into the job. Instrumenting the human for metabolic output (breathing gas analysis?) is an alternative that does exactly this, but introduces questions of fitness and technique into the problem taking you into the realm of sports physics/sports medicine. That's a rather specialized field far outside my expertise.

Comment: Thanks @dmckee. To further clarify, I don't want to measure a paddler's exertion as a stronger person or exertion doesn't necessarily correlate to proportional increase in boat speed. This is due to many factors, some of which include technical efficiency & correctness, the person's weight and height, etc... So, the measure would be only on the resultant effect of each stroke or series of strokes.